# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: wordpress, 4.7, php7

I am not a PHP/SQL programmer. Our CivicCRM is Version 4.7. PHP is 7.3.27. I upgraded our WordPress site to WP 5.6.1 and now get these errors:

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
in /home/rembrand/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php
on line 793

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started
at /home/rembrand/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php:793)
in /home/rembrand/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-header.php
on line 9

if (!count($dsn)) {
            return $parsed;
        }
```

Warning appears at top of screen when I enter Wordpress admin dashboard for our website and edit any page.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You appear to be trying to edit this question as a different user so your edits are pending review. Best if you can log in as the same user to make edits to your question.

Comment: I see in your edits that you're running CiviCRM 4.7.  This is many years out of date.  You'll need to upgrade CiviCRM to a version that supports your current version of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're running PHP 7.2 or greater with a version of CiviCRM that doesn't support PHP 7.2+.  If you edit your question to include your CiviCRM version, that could help folks troubleshoot.  However, it sounds like you may need to upgrade your CiviCRM to a version that supports 7.2.

Comment: Information about upgrading here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/